# Cannot add filter to SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've read some answers on the internet, but nothing helps to me. Cannot add filter to my springbootapplication. The guides say that if I need a filter that worked for all endpoints, that I need to use the Filter interface. I used it, but nothing has changed. Is there something wrong with my dependencies?

```
##### com.foo.core Main.java
package com.foo.core;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}

##### com.foo.core AuthorizationRequiredFilter.java
package com.foo.core;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(0)
public class AuthorizationRequiredFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationRequiredFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.debug("doFilter() method is invoked");
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        System.out.println(httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization"));
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}


##### com.foo.core PingController .java
package com.foo.core.controllers;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class PingController extends ResponseFormat {

    @RequestMapping(value = "ping", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String ping() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put("message", "pong");
        return this.ok(response);
    }

}


####### pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.businessdynamics</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>core</name>
    <description>Businessdynamics core</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I use `@SpringBootApplication` so componentscan is not required as I understand. When I `POST /ping` - I get server response, but I have no logs in my terminal. What I do wrong, why filter is not working?

Comment: Have you tried `jakarta.servlet.Filter` instead? Spring Boot 3 made the switch from javax to the jakarta dependencies: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M1-Release-Notes

Comment: oh, that was the exact problem, You can write it as an anster if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 switched from using `javax` packages to `jakarta` packages and dependencies: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M1-Release-Notes

Spring should be able to load the filter if you implement the `jakarta.servlet.Filter` class.